# How to summarise data for a span of time then skip a period of time and repeat?

Tags: r

I have a time series dataset that I would like to summarise. I want to take the mean of several values over 30 seconds, skip 60 seconds and then take the mean for the next 30 seconds and repeat this. Does anyone know of a way to do this in R?

| Time | Temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 5 | 17 |
| 6 | 22 |
| 7 | 15 |
| 8 | 13 |
| 9 | 8 |
| 10 | 12 |
| 11 | 21 |
| 12 | 5 |
| 13 | 9 |
| 14 | 11 |
| 15 | 19 |

Here is an example data set where I want to calculate the mean temperature for the first 5 seconds, skip 5 seconds and then calculate the mean temperature for the next 5 seconds and repeat this.

Comment: Could provide us the structure of the data using `dput()`?

Comment: Hi Will. I'm sure there are lots of ways of doing this in R, but they _all_ depend on the structure of your data. A description of your data isn't enough to help here. A reproducible example of your precise data structure is required. Please edit your question to include this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

`group` collects the blocks of 5 seconds by dividing `Time` by 5 and and taking the `ceiling` value. I assume here it is not 5 rows but seconds, so 1, 2, 3, and 5 are the first block.

`skip` marks the alternating blocks of 5 seconds using the `%%` modulus function

Then for the alternating groups, calculate the `mean`. If your real data includes NA `Temperature` values, then use `mean(Temperature, na.rm = TRUE)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~Time, ~Temperature,
  1, 5,
  2, 12,
  3, 15,
  5, 17,
  6, 22,
  7, 15,
  8, 13,
  9, 8,
  10, 12,
  11, 21,
  12, 5,
  13, 9,
  14, 11,
  15, 19
) |> 
  mutate(group = ceiling(Time / 5),
         skip = group %% 2) |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  mutate(mean_temp = if_else(skip == 1, mean(Temperature), NA_real_))

#> # A tibble: 14 × 5
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>     Time Temperature group  skip mean_temp
#>    <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1     1           5     1     1      12.2
#>  2     2          12     1     1      12.2
#>  3     3          15     1     1      12.2
#>  4     5          17     1     1      12.2
#>  5     6          22     2     0      NA  
#>  6     7          15     2     0      NA  
#>  7     8          13     2     0      NA  
#>  8     9           8     2     0      NA  
#>  9    10          12     2     0      NA  
#> 10    11          21     3     1      13  
#> 11    12           5     3     1      13  
#> 12    13           9     3     1      13  
#> 13    14          11     3     1      13  
#> 14    15          19     3     1      13
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>